# Google apps and OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am having an ASP.NET application that is integrating Google apps market place and there I am creating sub domain on that means my project is Scheduleonce so any one can access the scheduleonce from Google apps market place directly. So is it possible to access the market Place using OAuth process and currently we are on Google API version 2, and we are planning to move to version 3. So OAuth is supportable for Google Apps marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

I guess below links may help you to achieve your goal :-

http://blog.startq.com/index.php/2013/03/28/prevent-multiple-tabs-on-c-web-applications/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/201221/C-Sharp-how-restrict-the-user-from-opening-a-link-in-new-tab.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETPreventMultipleWind-b1dd2bd6

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the link that you sent me is not related to the topic.
This link that you sent are :
1) Prevent opening multiple windows in ASP.NET 
2) Prevent multiple tabs on C# web applications
But my issue is related to integrate google apps market place in asp.net application using OAuth